# How to get objects according to FK by using AJAX in django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I want to make a dropdown filter, which looks like this Auto Mark > Auto Model
As you can understand the "Auto Model" list should change every time Auto Mark changes, because the data must change without refreshing page i have to use AJAX.

My views.py looks like

```
def search_models(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''
    args['models'] = AutoModel.objects.filter(mark_id__exact='search-text')
    args['val'] = search_text
    return render_to_response('ajax-main-filter.html', args)
```

And my ajax-search.js looks like:

```
$(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/automobile/search/",
            data: {
                'search_text' : $('search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    });

});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

The problem is that variable 'search text' shows error or shows False value.

Please can someone help me...

Thank You

Comment: Can you write down what errors do you receive? And you sure that you should compare serach_text variable with mark_id and not something else?

Comment: Sure mark_id is the fk, if I write write it as constat 3 (as example), it filters the results it should. Filtering is true, the problem with te variable somehow...

Comment: it gives me search_text: None, instead of a value

Comment: Can you share the content of request.body and request.POST? Bonus points if you share the content-type header

Comment: <div>

search_test: {{ val }}
 
{% for model in models %}
 <li>{{ model.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</div>

It's the content of search.html which loads on request

Comment: <div class="large-6 columns">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
    <ul id="search-results">

    </ul>
   </div>

And it's the code on the main page which loads js, so the <input  type="text" id="search" name="search" />  becomes the key value for ajax script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your $('search').val() value is None, you should check why it could be.

Maybe its because you wrote wrong css selector and your selector should be

```
$('#search').val()
```

instead of

```
$('search').val()
```